# Elegant way to access objects created in qApplication main function

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a window application with Qt framework and C++, in which an object is created to operate hardware, and should be accessible to MainWindow and all its members and methods. I do not have very much experience of doing things like this.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication qApp(argc, argv);

    CoolHardware *CoolHardware500 = new CoolHardware;  // Object that connects to hardware.
    CoolHardware500.Connect();

    // Show main window here.
    MainWindow qApp_Win(CoolHardware500);  // This is the only elegant way I could think.
    qApp_Win.show();

    return qApp.exec();

    // Deconstructor.
    CoolHardware500>~CoolHardware();
}
```

In the methods of MainWindow,  is not accessible. How to solve this?

```
void MainWindow::CoolHardwareDoSomething() {
    CoolHardware500->DoSomehing(); // Here CoolHardware500 is shown as not defined.
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it an elegant way to create an hardware-operating object in the main() function? How to make it accessible to the members/methods of the MainWindow?
2. Is it better to create objects in the constructor of the MainWindow and deconstruct objects in the MainWindow deconstructor? In this way, accessing object is easy.
3. If this two ways are both not elegant ways of doing things, what is the elegant way of doing that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if you explicitly invoke the destructor of a dynamically created object (with plain `new`, not placement `new`) then you're doing something wrong. And destroying objects should be done before `return` as well.

Comment: Normally I don't create objects in int main() for a Qt application. I do however sometimes derive from  `QApplication` and create them there or in my QMainWindow.

Comment: Asking if a solution is "elegant" is asking for an opinion.

Comment: An easy fix for the destructor problem would be to use `std::unique_ptr<CoolHardware> CoolHardware500{std::make_unique<CoolHardware>};`

Comment: It *might* be meaningful, too, to implement the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). If *indeed* so – well, *you* need to decide ;)

Comment: Show your `MainWindow.h` header pls. I imagine you should have `std::unique_ptr<CoolHardware> _hw;` as your private field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. I was doing things in the constructor in the constructor of the mainwindow as drescherjm said. Things were working smoothly. I always wonder if there are other "elegant" ways of doing that, because I do not have systematic understanding of C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MainWindow` is subclassing QMainWindow, but it's a regular C++ class, so just store either an instance directly, or a pointer, as a member variable on it.

In MainWindow.h (or .hpp):

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    // Either this:
    CoolHardware500* m_coolHardwarePtr;
    // Or that:
    CoolHardware500 m_coolHardware;
};
```

In the constuctor `MainWindow::MainWindow` you can pass arguments to the `CoolHardware500` ctor as needed, or use a `new` if you use a pointer.

If using a pointer, you also want to have the destructor `MainWindow::~MainWindow` do a `delete m_coolHardwarePtr;`.

You could also use a smart pointer (like `std::unique_ptr`) to avoid to remember to do that delete yourself.

Mainwindow.cpp, assuming you have a Ctor `CoolHardware500::CoolHardware500(int)`:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
      m_coolHardware(1),
      m_coolHardwarePtr(new CoolHardware500(1))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete m_coolHardwarePtr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! At the moment I am using "CoolHardware500* m_coolHardwarePtr", but I didn't know that I need to delete the pointer. I learned C lang rather than C++ in college time 20 years ago.

Comment: Unless you have a reason to use a pointer, I would go with the instance as member.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how:

```
struct MainWindow : QMainWindow {
private:
  CoolHardware hardware;
  // ...

public:
  MainWindow() {
    hardware.connect();
    // ... 
  }
  // use `hardware` 

};
```

Comment: Thanks! I was doing things like this. It worked well. I just thought that this is not "elegant".

Comment: @tian_qhcn I would argue this is the most elegant way. It's certainly much better than dynamic allocation.